# creating polls in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, polling

I want to display a polls on the web application, so I created a `DataList` that displays the question and a template field `RadioButtonlist` to display each question answers, but the `RadioButtonList` only display one answer, so how I make the `RadioButtonList` display choices depending on the number of choices in the SQL source?
so my question generally is how to make RadioButtonList extend depending of the number of Data  it's displaying in the Data source?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here, could you show the code that you are using?

Comment: I didn't add any code yet, it's just from inside the wizard of the DataList

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz(v=vs.71).aspx

It even has the example displaying mutually exclusive options.

P.S : Please try and come back if you are stuck and ask more specific comments with details and error description , if any !